# String splitting in R Programming

Tags: r, split

Currently the script below is splitting a combined item code into a specific item codes.

```
rule2 <- c("MR")
df_1 <- test[grep(paste("^",rule2,sep="",collapse = "|"),test$Name.y),]

SpaceName_1 <- function(s){
  num <- str_extract(s,"[0-9]+")
  if(nchar(num) >3){
    former <- substring(s, 1, 4)
    latter <- strsplit(substring(s,5,nchar(s)),"")
    latter <- unlist(latter)
    return(paste(former,latter,sep = "",collapse = ","))
  }
  else{
    return (s)
  }
}

df_1$Name.y <- sapply(df_1$Name.y, SpaceName_1)
```

Example,
Combined item code: **Room 324-326** is splitting into **MR324 MR325 MR326**.

However for this particular Combined item code: **Room 309-311** is splitting into ***MR309 MR300 MR301***.

How should I amend the script to give me MR309 MR310 MR311?

Comment: I doubt `df_1$Name.y <- sapply(df_1$Name.y, SpaceName_1)` will work after splitting, as we will be creating a column with more rows than the original.

Answer (score 6):

You can try something along these lines:

```
range <- "324-326"
x <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(range, split="-")))
paste0("MR", seq(x[1], x[2]))

[1] "MR324" "MR325" "MR326"
```

I assume that you can obtain the numerical room sequence by some means, and then use the snippet I gave you above.

If your combined item codes always have the form `Room xxx-yyy`, then you can extract the range using `gsub`:

```
range <- gsub("Room ", "", "Room 324-326")
```

If your item codes were in a vector called `codes`, then you could obtain a vector of ranges using:

```
ranges <- sapply(codes, function(x) gsub("Room ", "", x))
```

Comment: I have multiple inputs such as Room 309-311, Room 308-310, Room 324-326, Room 334-336 etc. Input Room 324-326 and Room 334-336 is splitting correctly into MR324, MR325, MR326 and MR334, MR335, MR336 respectively, However, input such as Room 309-311 and Room 308-310 is not splitting correctly. For Room 309-311, The script is splitting it wrongly,into MR309, MR300, MR301. I would want the script to split it into MR309, MR310, MR311

Answer (score 1):

We can also evaluate the string after replacing the `-` with `:` and then `paste` the prefix "MR".

```
paste0("MR", eval(parse(text=sub("\\S+\\s+(\\d+)-(\\d+)", "\\1:\\2", range))))
#[1] "MR324" "MR325" "MR326"
```

Wrap it as a function for convenience

```
fChange <- function(prefixStr, RangeStr){ 
 paste0(prefixStr, eval(parse(text=sub("\\S+\\s+(\\d+)-(\\d+)", 
             "\\1:\\2", RangeStr))))
 }

fChange("MR", range)
fChange("MR", range1)
#[1] "MR309" "MR310" "MR311"
```

For multiple elements, just loop over and apply the function

```
sapply(c(range, range1), fChange, prefixStr = "MR")
```

#### data

```
range <- "Room 324-326"
range1 <- "Room 309-311"
```