# String Splitting in R

Tags: r, regex, split

The Script below is splitting Item code;

Example

`MR32456` into `MR324, MR325, MR326`.

`MR3091011` into `MR309, MR301, MR300, MR301, MR301`

How should i amend the script so that for `MR3091011`, it will split into `MR309, MR310, MR311`?

```
  rule2 <- c("MR")
    df_1 <- test[grep(paste("^",rule2,sep="",collapse = "|"),test$Name.y),]

SpaceName_1 <- function(s){
  num <- str_extract(s,"[0-9]+")
  if(nchar(num) >3){
    former <- substring(s, 1, 4)
    latter <- strsplit(substring(s,5,nchar(s)),"")
    latter <- unlist(latter)
    return(paste(former,latter,sep = "",collapse = ","))
  }
  else{
    return (s)
  }
}

df_1$Name.y <- sapply(df_1$Name.y, SpaceName_1)
```

Comment: Related, maybe duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39591010

Comment: Room numbers are always 3 digits?

Comment: I think in the first case you have a typo.  Shouldn't it be  `MR326`

Comment: @zx8754 yes, room numbers are always 3 digits

Comment: How do we know the difference between `MR324_56` and `MR324_56_58` (added "_" to illustrate the problem). How do we know if it is a single digit or 2 digit following first 3 main digits.

Comment: We got same related post yesterday

Comment: The only 2 digit following the first 3 main digits are 10 and 11

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing a split function from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26497583/split-a-string-every-5-characters), and vectorizing it, we can do the following,

```
fun1 <- function(x){ 
  sapply(seq(from=1, to=nchar(substr(x, 4, nchar(x))), by=2), function(i) substr(substr(x, 4, nchar(x)), i, i+1))
} 

fun1 <- Vectorize(fun1)

Map(paste0, substr(x, 1, 3), fun1(x))

#$MR3
#[1] "MR309" "MR310" "MR311"

#$MR3
#[1] "MR324" "MR356"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
str <- 'MR3091011'
paste(substring(str,1,4), strsplit(str,"")[[1]][-(1:4)], sep='')

[1] "MR309" "MR301" "MR300" "MR301" "MR301"
```

for a list of strings you can try:

```
strlst <- c("MR32456", "MR3091011")
lapply(strlst, function(str) paste(substring(str,1,4), 
                                   strsplit(str,"")[[1]][-(1:4)], sep=''))    
[[1]]
[1] "MR324" "MR325" "MR326"

[[2]]
[1] "MR309" "MR301" "MR300" "MR301" "MR301"
```

***[EDIT]***

```
groups <- unlist(strsplit(sub('([[:alpha:]]+)(\\d)(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})', '\\1 \\2 \\3 \\4 \\5', 'MR3091011'), split=' '))
paste0(groups[1], groups[2], groups[3:5])
# [1] "MR309" "MR310" "MR311"
```

Comment: @Sotos: yes got OP wrong, updated with a regexp-based solution.